# What is the order of the C preprocessor macro expansion?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

English is not my native language; thus I show the code to depict.

```
#define concat_temp(x, y) x##y
#define concat(x, y) concat_temp(x, y)
#define CHOOSE2nd(a, b, ...) b
#define MUX_WITH_COMMA(contain_comma, a, b) CHOOSE2nd(contain_comma a, b)
#define MUX_MACRO_PROPERTY(p, macro, a, b) MUX_WITH_COMMA(concat(p, macro), a, b)
#define __P_DEF_0 X,
#define __P_DEF_1 X,
#define MUXDEF(macro, X, Y) MUX_MACRO_PROPERTY(__P_DEF_, macro, X, Y)
#define ISDEF(macro) MUXDEF(macro, 1, 0)

#define FOO 1

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    ISDEF(FOO) // 1
    MUXDEF(FOO, 1, 0) // 1
    MUX_MACRO_PROPERTY(__P_DEF_, FOO, 1, 0) // 1
    MUX_WITH_COMMA(concat(__P_DEF_, FOO), 1, 0) // 1

    CHOOSE2nd(concat(__P_DEF_, FOO) 1, 0) // 0 !!! why?
    
    concat(__P_DEF_, FOO) // X,

    CHOOSE2nd(X, 1, 0) // 1


    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to expand the macro `ISDEF` manually, but I ran into some trouble.

When the macro is defined as 0 or 1, the `ISDEF` will be expanded to 1.
However, there are more args that need to be expanded in `MUX_WITH_COMMA(concat(__P_DEF_, FOO), 1, 0)` which are `MUX_WITH_COMMA` and `concat`;
I think the former will be expanded first in that `MUX_WITH_COMMA(X,, 1, 0)` is incorrect.

In the line which I expand manually `CHOOSE2nd(concat(__P_DEF_, FOO) 1, 0)` the first expansion is `CHOOSE2nd` and the result is 0;
but in the original expression the order should be

1. `MUX_WITH_COMMA` -> `CHOOSE2nd`
2. `concat(__P_DEF_, FOO)` -> `X,`
3. `CHOOSE2nd(X, 1, 0)` -> `1`

I guess that the preprocessor will expand the args in the brackets after processing the other part just once, and then repeat this process until no macro can be expanded.
Is it the right explanation?

Another likely possible order is that the preprocessor will prioritize the args in bracket, like this:

```
    ISDEF(1) // 1
    MUXDEF(1, 1, 0) // 1
    MUX_MACRO_PROPERTY(__P_DEF_, 1, 1, 0) // 1
    MUX_WITH_COMMA(concat(__P_DEF_, 1), 1, 0) // 1
    CHOOSE2nd(concat(__P_DEF_, 1) 1, 0) // 0
    CHOOSE2nd(X, 1, 0) // 1
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve, the end result is code that doesn't look like any C++ I could recognize. The use of macros isn't recommended, and should only be used if other typesafe options like (variadic) templates have been tried. Also tag your question either as "C" or as "C++" they are different languages.

Comment: Any reason to go such have kind with macros? If C++ is not the language which fits, you may try another one?

Comment: Please don't write code like this. It makes my eyes hurt :)

Comment: It seems you have forgotten a comma. This: `CHOOSE2nd(concat(__P_DEF_, FOO) 1, 0)` should be this: `CHOOSE2nd(concat(__P_DEF_, FOO), 1, 0)` - with `,` after the `concat()` call.

Comment: @PeterKrebs No, the `concat(__P_DEF_, FOO), 1, 0)` will be replaced with `X,`

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy In fact, it's not my code; I'm reading a .h file which includes hundreds of lines of macros...

Comment: `MUX_WITH_COMMA(concat(p, macro), a, b)` will expand the `concat(p, macro)` macro before `CHOOSE2nd(contain_comma a, b)` is expanded. So your whole `CHOOSE2nd(concat(__P_DEF_, FOO) 1, 0) // 0 !!! why?` is a false premise.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But in that case `MUX_WITH_COMMA(X,, 1, 0)` will received a compile error.. because of its double commas.

Answer (score 2):

- Expand `ISDEF(FOO)`

  - Expand `FOO`

    -> `1`

  -> `MUXDEF(1, 1, 0)`
- Expand `MUXDEF(macro, X, Y)`

  -> `MUX_MACRO_PROPERTY(__P_DEF_, 1, 1, 0)`
- Expand `MUX_MACRO_PROPERTY(p, macro, a, b)`

  -> `MUX_WITH_COMMA(concat(__P_DEF_, 1), 1, 0)`

  - Expand `concat(x, y)`

    -> `concat_temp(__P_DEF_, 1)`
  - Expand `concat_temp(__P_DEF_, 1)`

    -> `__P_DEF_##1`
  - Apply `##`

    -> `__P_DEF_1`
  - Expand `__P_DEF_1`

    -> `X,`

  -> `MUX_WITH_COMMA(X, 1, 0)`
- Expand `MUX_WITH_COMMA(contain_comma, a, b)`

  -> `CHOOSE2nd(X, 1, 0)`
- Expand `CHOOSE2nd(a, b, ...)`

  -> `1`

---

- Expand `ISDEF(BAR)`

  -> `MUXDEF(BAR, 1, 0)`
- Expand `MUXDEF(macro, X, Y)`

  -> `MUX_MACRO_PROPERTY(__P_DEF_, BAR, 1, 0)`
- Expand `MUX_MACRO_PROPERTY(p, macro, a, b)`

  -> `MUX_WITH_COMMA(concat(__P_DEF_, BAR), 1, 0)`

  - Expand `concat(x, y)`

    -> `concat_temp(__P_DEF_, BAR)`
  - Expand `concat_temp(__P_DEF_, BAR)`

    -> `__P_DEF_##BAR`
  - Apply `##`

    -> `__P_DEF_BAR`

  -> `MUX_WITH_COMMA(__P_DEF_BAR, 1, 0)`
- Expand `MUX_WITH_COMMA(contain_comma, a, b)`

  -> `CHOOSE2nd(__P_DEF_BAR 1, 0)`
- Expand `CHOOSE2nd(a, b, ...)`

  -> `0`

Comment: Thx.My trouble occurred at `Expand MUX_WITH_COMMA(contain_comma, a, b)` because `MUX_WITH_COMMA(X,, 1, 0)` is illegal and I have wrapped my head around it now.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the order of the C preprocessor macro expansion?

Let's say macro expansion works like this:

- First arguments are recognized. Arguments are separated by all `,`  that are not inside `(` `)`. So like `MACRO( (,) , (,,,,,,,,) )` calls `MACRO` with two arguments.
- Then the macro is expanded.

  - All arguments that are part of `#` or `##` are replaced literally.
  - All other cases of argumetns are beeing replaced by expansions.
- Then the result of that macro expansion is "rescanned" again, and we go to back to point 1.

Because first macro arguments are recognized, that's why it takes like two expansions "down" for a comma to change number of arguments. I mean, the `MUX_WITH_COMMA(concat(__P_DEF_, 1), 1, 0)` expands to `MUX_WITH_COMMA(X, 1, 0)` which is then "rescanned".

Comment: `No, because MUX_WITH_COMMA takes 3 arguments. X,, 1,0 are 4 arguments - X, empty, 1 and 0.` yep I mean the same.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have still not found a reliable reference to explain it, it seems that the expanded arg which contains comma will not be counted as two args. Like this:

```
#define FOO(x) x
#define A a,a

int main() {
    FOO(A) // a,a
}
```

Thus the correct order in the question is that:

```
ISDEF(1) // 1
    MUXDEF(1, 1, 0) // 1
    MUX_MACRO_PROPERTY(__P_DEF_, 1, 1, 0) // 1
    MUX_WITH_COMMA(concat(__P_DEF_, 1), 1, 0) // 1
    //MUX_WITH_COMMA(X,, 1, 0) // compile error
    //But if the `X,` is expand by a macro it will not be count as two args.
    CHOOSE2nd(X, 1, 0) // 1
```

Comment: The whole process of 'macro replacement' is defined in the C standard [§6.10.3 Macro replacement](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10.3).  It isn't an easy read, but it is definitive.